# if condition with brackets doesn't work in js

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm so sorry for asking this question but I'm losing my mind over here.

I've this if-statement:

```
if (($('.alt_menu').text() !== 'Status' && $.trim($('.txt__adminLog_logs').text()).length > 15 && input_adminLog_about!==''&&isCalling_org!=='0') && ((input_adminLog_helped !=='') || (isCalling_org === '0' && $('.input_adminLog_helped').css('display') === 'none'))) {}
```

This if-statement checks for everything except `&& ((input_adminLog_helped !=='') || (isCalling_org === '0' && $('.input_adminLog_helped').css('display') === 'none'))`

I've also tried without brackets and I still get the same result.

**Good to know**

`$('.alt_menu').text()` is a home-made dropdown menu, `$('.txt__adminLog_logs').text()` is a contenteditable div and should've have more than 15 characters, `input_adminLog_about` is a variable that contains information and shouldn't be empty, `isCalling_org` is a global variable and can be 0 or eg. *`5705485375`*

`input_adminLog_helped` can be empty if `$('.input_adminLog_helped').css('display') === 'none'` and `isCalling_org === 0` otherwise it's has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the brackets. It was `$('.input_adminLog_helped').css('display') === 'none'`.

It should be `$('.input_adminLog_helped').is(':hidden')`